# Do you 'scale' or 'climb' a tree?

Tags: semantics

I know 'I climbed the pine tree' would work.

but…

Could you say 'I scaled the pine tree'?

Comment: Hello, Jakub. Are dictionaries of no help here? Reasonable research is expected to accompany questions on ELU.

Answer (score 1):

Under normal circumstances, trees are *climbed* in English, not *scaled*. To scale a tree, however, suggests climbing one with particular agility and speed:

> According to the kid, Evans could scale a tree like a squirrel. — [M. William Phelps, *Every Move You Make*, 2003.](https://books.google.de/books?id=EqDiAgAAQBAJ&pg=PT83&dq=%22scale%20a%20tree%22&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjTiuLIsZbZAhVFaVAKHfvwDNE4ChDoAQgnMAI)

Otherwise, *scale* appears as the go-to synonym when a writer wants to use *climb* with another object:

> “I hop a fence, scale a tree, and climb over that railing, all with my hands full of stuff for you. And you won't let me in.” — [Cassie Mae, *Friday Night Alibi: A Rouge Contemporary Romance*, 2013.](https://books.google.de/books?id=roxbAgAAQBAJ&pg=PT99&dq=%22scale%20a%20tree%22&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjTiuLIsZbZAhVFaVAKHfvwDNE4ChDoAQghMAE)
>
> Days of watching others climb a steep slope or scale a tree made me wonder: Why did my feet refuse to do what others could? [Mims Cushing, *You Can Cope with Peripheral Neuropathy*, 2009.](https://books.google.de/books?id=cc1OVT739f8C&pg=PA155&dq=%22scale%20a%20tree%22&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjTiuLIsZbZAhVFaVAKHfvwDNE4ChDoAQgyMAQ)

Here, *scale* and *climb* could be switched out with no loss of meaning.

Comment: Useful, but dictionaries give a better overview of usage. Here, the 'as if using a ladder' (particular agility and speed) caveat is given by some but not others, and a good answer would reference these.

Answer (score -1):

Technically, "scale" means to climb using a ladder *or as if using a ladder*.  It would be appropriate if you want to convey a steady ladder-like ascent, but some might object if you describe a more random approach to the climb.

Comment: Does 'technically' mean 'according to some of the definitions given by some of the reputable online dictionaries'?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth -- Sigh!  I made the above an answer rather than a comment because I've been criticized of late for doing the opposite.  If you feel it needs more detail to be considered an "answer" you are welcome to edit it and add that info.

Comment: I believe it needs correcting. Using the word 'technically' to mean 'judging by the Latin root', '300 years ago' or 'in the first (and only) dictionary I looked in' has been heavily criticised before on ELU (and not by me).

Comment: That’s not what scale means. You can scale something without a ladder.